# UIMapView iPad - Address look up

Tags: iphone, ipad, street-address, mkmapview

Our app has addresses like "123 Main St, Perth, Wa, 6554, Australia"

We need to display a map with that address. Is there a way to get the UIMap view to lookup the address and display?

Normally we'd have the Lat/Long and would just put that in with a pin annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google's Geocoding Api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to first get Lat/Long for the address, and then load that in UIMapView.